# Adding new field with Unique key index in existing MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a column with Unique Key (so it will not have duplicate records) in existing MySQL table that contains multiple rows of data.

```
ALTER TABLE  `common`.`fraud_payment_log`
  ADD  `retainer_id` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
  ADD  `http_referrer` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
  ADD UNIQUE (`retainer_id`);
```

But it is throwing below error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'retainer_id'
```

The error is because of the duplicate empty value which will come when we adding a new column in the existing table with records.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: You could be interested by http://stackoverflow.com/a/512485/14673

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Creating new unique field in already populated table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733573/mysql-creating-new-unique-field-in-already-populated-table)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a unique, non-NULL column to a table that has more than one row.  By definition, two rows would get the same value.

Add the columns first, allowing NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE  `common`.`fraud_payment_log`
    ADD  `retainer_id` VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    ADD  `http_referrer` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL;
```

Now, populate the column so it has different values.  Say:

```
update `common`.`fraud_payment_log` cross join
       (select @rn := 0) vars
     set retainer_id = (@rn := @rn + 1);
```

Then add the unique constraint.  I usually do this with the index directly:

```
create unique index idx_fpl_retainer on  `common`.`fraud_payment_log`(retainer_id);
```

If the table is empty, then just recreate the table with all the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- Add new field which is not unique
- Update table and put unique values in that field
- Alter table to make this field as unique

Answer (score 0):

You should first add the column, then populate it with the unique values, then add the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a `DEFAULT NULL`; NULL doesn't count against UNIQUE checks, so your table will be first filled with NULL values, then you'll proceed to fill it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new column using UI or query(My new column is **sensorID**)
2. Fire this :

> UPDATE client set sensorID=id

3. In above query **client** is my table , **sensorID** is my newly added column on which I wanted to apply unique, **id** is my primary key type column in existing table.